# Real analytic function $I\to \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Let $I=(0,1)$ be an open interval , $\gamma: I\to \mathbb C$ be a curve such that there exists an open subset $\Omega\subset \mathbb C$ containing $I$ (identifying $t\in (0,1)$ as $t+i0$) and $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ an analytic function whose restriction to $I$ is $\gamma$.   Similar type of real analytic curve $\gamma: I\to \mathbb R$.

$D: U\subset \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ and  $\alpha: I\to U$ be a $C^1$ map such that $D\circ \alpha= \gamma$ (for some $\gamma$ as defined in the previous paragraph)..  Can we say something about analyticity  of $D$ on some point on trace of $\alpha$.

Comment: Should "containing $I$" be "containing $\gamma(I)$" ?

Comment: Or is $I$ an interval in $\mathbb C$? (If $z_0, z_1 \in \mathbb C$ then $[z_0, z_1] = \{ z = (1-t) z_0 + t z_1 \mid 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited the question.  does it make sense now.

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't see any reason to treat $I$ as a subset of $\mathbb C$, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\gamma(t) = t$, $\Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| < 1 \}$ and $f(z) = z$. Next take $U = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z-\frac12| < \frac12$, $D(z) = |z|$ and $\alpha(t) = t$.

Then both $D$ and $\alpha$ are $C^1$ and $D \circ \alpha = \gamma$ but $D$ is *not* analytic in any point of $I$. If we instead take $D(z) = z$ then we also get $D \circ \alpha = \gamma$ and in this case $D$ is analytic in all points of $I$.

Thus nothing can be said about the analyticity of $D$.